# Field output object not iterable

Tags: python, abaqus

I tried the follwing code and tried to read eseden from a nodeset. I get the following error as "Type error Field output object is not iterable".

Aravind

```
from odbAccess import *
from textRepr import *
from abaqusConstants import *
import odbAccess
odb=openOdb(path='python2d.odb')

NodesofInterest = odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1'].nodeSets['NODESET'] 

eseden=odb.steps['Step-1'].frames[1].fieldOutputs['ESEDEN'].getSubset(region=NodesofInterest)

for v in eseden:
    print v
    print (v.elementLabel,v.data)
```

Comment: Can you do a `print eseden`? What is it exactly?

Comment: and a print type(eseden)

Comment: Why don't you try `len(eseden)` - maybe its only one thing and thus no point looping over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `getSubset` called on `fieldOutputs` repository returns a `FieldOutput` object. That object contains a member `values`, which can be used to read values for a specific variable, 'ESEDEN' in your case.

Member `values` is actually a `FieldValueArray` with `FieldValue` objects, each with all the necessary information about data for a single node.

The reason you're getting an error is that 'FieldOutput' object is really not iterable, so to retrieve the actual information, you need to follow connections as I've just described.

To make this description somewhat more clear, here's a simple example using your code:

```
from odbAccess import *
from textRepr import *
from abaqusConstants import *
import odbAccess

odb=openOdb(path='python2d.odb')

NodesofInterest = odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1'].nodeSets['NODESET'] 
eseden=odb.steps['Step-1'].frames[1].fieldOutputs['ESEDEN'].getSubset(region=NodesofInterest)

# This kind of iteration should work since FieldValueArray is not 
# a repository
for value in eseden.values:
    # Should print node's label and corresponding value
    print value.nodelabel, value.data
```

You can read more about this if you search for FieldOutput and FieldValue in the [documentation](http://www.oulu.fi/tietohallinto/unix/abaqus_docs/v6.13/books/ker/default.htm). Unfortunately, I can't find a way to directly link any part of documentation separately.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your reply. I tried running the example you have provided me. But it is not printing anything. The code just runs. Can you please help me with that.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Where are you looking for output, in Abaqus' command line?

Comment: Yes Sir. I checked in abaqus message window

Comment: Try printing out len(eseden.values) to see if there are even any values for that variable and those nodes.

Comment: Hello Sir, It returns value '0'. but I can see the nodesets under the assembly -instance-sets. I can view the results in visualisation by creating a display group for the nodesets. Please suggest me what i can do to view the values

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. I just sorted it out. The element set I have created is directly under the assembly not in the instance. node set wont work because the ESEDEN is an elemental value. And it works fine now. Thank you so much for your time and guidance. Merry Christmas and happy new year.

Comment: No problem, it's great that you managed to figure it out by yourself. Merry Christmas and happy new year to you, too.